# XFCE: What is causing and how can I fix elements rendering oversized on second screen (but correctly on the first one) for VLC and VMWare?

Tags: multiple-monitors, xfce

Some time ago (I believe after installing `VM VirtualBOX` and experimenting with guest VM settings - different display graphic controllers to try make Sketchup work under windows, but I'm not certain that is what broke it)..

rendering a few of the GUI applications I use has broken - `VLC`, `Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager`, `VidCutter`

but only on my second screen.

[image: VLC rendering on screen0]

[image: VLC rendering on screen1]

both screens are same monitors.
I've been learning a lot about linuxes for the past 4 years but not about X11 yet.

I've heard it might be DPI and could only find this one setting in
`Settings Manager→Appearances→Fonts` and tried it on and off to no avail.

Since it's only VLC, VMWare and I don't remember what (edit: [VidCutter](https://github.com/ozmartian/vidcutter)) (all others and system windows render correctly on both screens) I'm thinking it must be some library these two share, but I know nothing about how to detect it or even what to do with that knowledge.

I've searched whole `/etc/X11/` folder but found nothing helpful there..

Any ideas?

this is xrandr output:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1200, maximum 8192 x 8192
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00
   1600x1200     60.00
   1680x1050     59.95
   1280x1024     60.02
   1440x900      59.89
   1280x960      60.00
   1024x768      60.00
   800x600       60.32
   640x480       59.94
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected 1920x1200+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00
   1600x1200     60.00
   1680x1050     59.95
   1280x1024     60.02
   1440x900      59.89
   1280x960      60.00
   1024x768      60.00
   800x600       60.32
   640x480       59.94
```

I notice one screen has `518mm x 324mm`, and the other `160mm x 90mm` next to it but I've no clue as to where is that set up.

The system is Xubuntu 18.04.

What other information can I provide here to help fix this?

Also I noticed, that modifying DPI in `Settings Manager→Appearances→Fonts` affects all the other applications but not VLC and VM and that goes for both monitors.

Trying

```
$ xrandr --output DP-2 --dpi 96
$ xrandr --output DP-3 --dpi 96
$ xrandr | grep -w connected
DP-2 connected 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
DP-3 connected 1920x1200+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
```

has not changed a thing, and did not recalculate the dimensions in mm's - it must be set elsewhere?

```
xrandr --output DP-3 --scale 1x1
```

also yielded no result, setting it to 2x2 works on everything, but VLC seems to have it's own rendering and as it get's scaled by the xrandr manipulation together with everything else (like scale 2x2 vs 1x1), it also has some other effects applied.

I believe now that this is completely independent of xrandr and must be the specific library that renders VLC - I guess I'll have to research that...

These two things lead me to believe, the issue is with this Qt library...
https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18942
https://wiki.videolan.org/Qt_and_GTK/

The workaround suggested in the VirtualBox ticket did not help either:

```
export QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS="1;1"
```

Comment: This has some good info in it:  https://winaero.com/find-change-screen-dpi-linux/

Comment: What OS & release(s) are you talking about ?  (given they are VMs, are they using the same host settings?)

Comment: guiverc: I'm on Xubuntu 18.04. We are not talking about VMs here, just the host system. (Meddling with the VM's settings is the only thing I vaguely remember as anything concerning graphics that occurred in the same time-span as this failure)

Comment: @Terrance, thanks for the tip, but those tools mentioned there (xdpyinfo, xfconf-query) don't differentiate settings into specific monitors, just generally screen :0.0 
Any other ideas? :>

Comment: @MichałLepczyński That is just the info.  You use `xrandr` to set the dpi per monitor.  It shows you below how to get that info.  Then you would use `xrandr --dpi ###x### --output <monitor>`

Comment: @Terrance, that did not help (see addition at the bottom of the question) :-(

Comment: One other thing I can think of is the scaling.  Try `xrandr --output DP-3 --scale 1x1`.

Comment: @Terrance, thanks again, no luck, I've updated the question, I believe now, that xrandr has nothing to do with it altogether.